# Reading the Data from a CSV File on Drop Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to read the CSV data while uploading, but not I'm not able to get the data.

I am dropping the data on the 'div' tag and not on the 'input' tag.

```
 onDrop = (e: React.DragEvent)=>{
        console.log("the value of event is ",e, e.dataTransfer.files);

        let files = e.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object

 // the value of files is 
 //lastModified: 1557969398000
 //lastModifiedDate: Thu May 16 2019 06:46:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard 
 //Time) {}
 //name: "2388278.csv"
 //size: 17934
 //type: "text/csv"
 //webkitRelativePath: ""

        let f = files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let output = reader.readAsText(f);
        console.log("output", output); // out put value id undefined

}
```

Comment: how to read the csv data in text , by droping on the div tag :(
plz kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fileReader onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) function to

- get access to the file content trough fileReader.result
- split each row by `\n`
- split each row content by `,`

Done the above you will get an array where each element of the array corresponds to a row in the CSV file.

In this way if you have for example a users.csv file with the content

```
001,admin,admin.user@domain.com
002,user,user@domain.com
```

You will get the following output

```
[['001', 'admin', 'admin.user@domain.com'], ['002', 'user', 'user@domain.com']]
```

Please try the following example

```
const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.readAsText(file);

fileReader.onload = function() {
    const dataset = fileReader.result;

    const result = dataset.split('\n').map(data => data.split(','));

    console.log(result);
};
```